# onerorr callback method does not fire.  is an event listener needed?

Tags: javascript

I dynamically create DOM elements based upon the user input using this code (Example 1).  I also use php/xhtml to create the same elements on a reload (Example 2).

Problem I'm seeing is that my image onerror event only works for the reloaded version.  Here I use traditional inline event registration to `i_bm_err` and it works.

However for the javascript version, the onerorr callback method does not fire.

My questions:  Do I need to add an event Listener?  If so, what is the event listener's type?  I have tried adding event listeners of type "error" and "onerror", but this did not work.  This makes me think that maybe adding and evernt listener is not the issue.

Example 1

```
function o3(a)  
  {
  return document.createElement(a);
  }

  var b=o3('a');
    b.innerHTML=c[1].value;
    b.href=c[2].value;
    b.name="a1";
    b.className="b";
    b.target="_blank";
  var e=o3('img');
    e.className="c";
    e.name="bo_im";
    e.src=b.href+'favicon.ico';
    e.onerror=function(e){e.src='http://www.archemarks.com/favicon1.ico';};
```

Example 2

PHP / XHTML

```
  function bookmarks()
    {
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM bo  WHERE email='$email' ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($ass_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {
      $fav=$this->fav($ass_array['url']);
      echo "<img name=\"bo_im\" class=\"c\" src=\"$fav\"/ onerror=\"i_bm_err(this)\"><a target=\"_blank\" name = \"a1\" class = \"b\" href = \"$ass_array[url]\">$ass_array[name]</a>";
      }
    }
```

Javascript

```
function i_bm_err(a)
  {
  a.src='http://www.archemarks.com/favicon1.ico';
  }
```

Research:

[MDN - element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

> In the example above, the value of this within modifyText() when
>   called from the click event is a reference to the table 't'. This is
>   in contrast to the behavior that occurs if the handler is added in the
>   HTML source:

Comment: What does the `o3` function do? Does it create the element *and* add it to the DOM? In which case, setting the image's `src` property *before* attching the error handler might not work.

Comment: Wow. Are you *trying* to obfuscate your code while writing it? If you need it that bad, use a minifier/obfuscater afterwards.

Comment: I was writing minimized code...I am reverting it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paul Grime mentioned, you need to attach all your events (error, load etc) prior to setting the src attribute.